# change color of Google logo on maps

Tags: google-maps

I would like only to change color of google logo by using filter: brightness(0) invert(1); which fairly easy to do. But I am not sure if this breaks terms of service, anybody can help ?[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about terms of use (legal issues) not coding.

Comment: related issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 8650: Monochromatic Google Logo Without White Glow](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8650)

Comment: related issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 9434: Make it possible to switch between colored and white logo](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9434)

Comment: related issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 2574: Google Logo (default or white version)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2574)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't . reference: https://www.google.com/permissions/trademark/rules.html

> don't remove, distort or alter any element of a Google Brand Feature.
>   That includes modifying a Google trademark

and

> Use only Google-approved artwork when using Google's logos.

They made it quite clear ;)